# drawing keypoints with emgucv

Tags: c#, debugging, matching, emgucv

I am using EmguCV and C# on MS VisualStudio 2013
I had made an XML file containing the descriptors of several images and then I am matching this descriptors (as observed image) with the observed image descriptors (as model image) in order to see which KeyPoints are being used. (kind of inverse matching).

I have the following code working for some images as input and for some I get the exception:
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

As I make a breakpoint on the line where XX is assigned, all the variables are correct but after some iterations the Exception is thrown. 
That is my main question: **why does it happen to some pictures?** (not depending on the picture format)
And one more thing strange here is that the color of the KeyPoints on the resulting picture is not pure Red (0,0,255) as I expect it to be. Can anyone tell me why?

Here is my code:

```
SURFDetector surfCPU = new SURFDetector(500, false);  
Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
Matrix<int> indices;
int k = 1;
// extract features from the observed image
observedKeyPoints = surfCPU.DetectKeyPointsRaw(imgGray, null);
Matrix<float> observedDescriptors = surfCPU.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(imgGray, null, observedKeyPoints);
BruteForceMatcher<float> matcher55 = new BruteForceMatcher<float>(DistanceType.L2);

matcher55.Add(observedDescriptors);
indices = new Matrix<int>(AgrObjectDescriptors.Rows, k);

using (Matrix<float> dist = new Matrix<float>(AgrObjectDescriptors.Rows, k))
{
    matcher55.KnnMatch(AgrObjectDescriptors, indices, dist, k, null);
    Debug.Write(matcher55);
}

/*The following is the problem part  */
int XX,YY;
Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr KeyPointColor =  new Bgr(0, 0, 255);
MKeyPoint[] usedKeyP = observedKeyPoints.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Rows; i++) {
    XX = Convert.ToInt32(usedKeyP[indices[i, 0]].Point.X);
    YY = Convert.ToInt32(usedKeyP[indices[i, 0]].Point.Y);
    img99[XX, YY] = KeyPointColor;
}
/*Draw the image on WPF component image1*/
 image1.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(img99);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you get the exception when your descriptors are empty. I've gotten similar errors when that has happened, so check to see if that is why. That would explain why some images work and some don't, as some images could have good matches and others may not.

Comment: thank you for your answer!  All the data arrays were checked beforehand and during debug too. XX and YY always have values.  The problem is not there, it is in the line img99[XX, YY] = KeyPointColor; If that line is not used it works fine.